# Как заменить на NULL строку (ячейку), если она содержит нецифровой символ?

Tags: postgresql

Добрый день!
Пожалуйста, подскажите, как заменить на NULL ячейку, если она содержит нецифровой символ?

```
select NULLIF('строка', ???)
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select case when COLUMN ~ '[^\d]' then NULL else COLUMN end
  from TableX
```